# Can't figure out why my print statement keeps printing out twice

Tags: c

hey guys so I have this code i'm working with and it's doing everything i need it to do, however, i can't figure out why my printf is printing out twice for level. here is the code.

```
while(fgets(str_read, sizeof(str_read)-1 , fptr)!= NULL)
    sscanf(str_read, "%d ", &somearray->level);
    printf("level: %d\n", somearray->level);
```

also if there is anything else i could work on im open to feed back. i'm working with a .txt file that has the following setup:

```
int
name
int
name
int
name
```

Comment: "here's the code"? I think not, unless it's somehow encoded in the period at the end of that sentence :-)

Comment: sorry i was having issues. still new so still getting my sea legs.

Comment: also if anyone want to school me on how to do those cool code snipets with my own comments, i'm open for it also.

Comment: Ryan, you can either put at least four spaces at the start of every code line (and a blank line before and after), or surround your code with triple backticks. For that first option, you can mark unindented text and then just use CTRL-K.

Comment: Presuming `str_read` is an array, `sizeof(str_read)-1` simply needs to be `sizeof(str_read)`, there is no `-1` with `fgets()`, it will guarantee the resulting string is *nul-terminated*. Also `printf("level: %d\n", somearray->level);` is NOT part of your loop. C isn't Python....

Comment: thanks pax i'll definetly use that the next time around. and thanks @whoami for the edits.

Comment: Thanks David. I was wondering about that also. I kept it because i thought it would eliminate the \n at the end of the text. But definetly will make that correct. Also yes the str_read is an array. Also the printf is actually in the while loop, I just didn't know how to enter the brackets on to here. Still learning

Comment: That's how you learn -- we all started at the same place.. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return value from `sscanf`.  On lines that don't contain an integer, it will return `0`.  In that case, `somearray->level` will be unchanged, so you'll print it a second time.

One possible solution is:

```
while(fgets(str_read, sizeof(str_read)-1 , fptr)!= NULL)
    if (sscanf(str_read, "%d ", &somearray->level) == 1)
        printf("level: %d\n", somearray->level);
```

This attempts the `sscanf` for every line, but only prints the result if a value was found.

Another solution would be to keep track of even vs. odd lines, and only attempt the `sscanf` on odd lines.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the help. Appreciate it

Comment: @Ryanv048 - your takeaways here are (1) you ***validate*** EVERY user-input and (2) you ***validate*** EVERY conversion. You do that so you know you have a valid value before proceeding to use that value in your code. Failure to validate invites *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm going to assume your code has braces around it since otherwise, it would only print once at the end (braces control what's in a loop body, not indentation):

```
while(fgets(str_read, sizeof(str_read)-1 , fptr)!= NULL) {
    sscanf(str_read, "%d ", &somearray->level);
    printf("level: %d\n", somearray->level);
}
```

That gels with what you're seeing. If your text file consists of alternating integers and non-integer names, every second `sscanf` will fail because a name cannot be treated as an integer. Since you don't check the return value, you just blindly assume the conversion worked and print the value that was previously in `somearray->level`.

Calls to the `scanf` family of function should generally include a check to ensure everything was correctly scanned, something like:

```
if (sscanf(str_read, "%d ", &somearray->level) != 1) {
    handleBadScan();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pax Thats really good to know. I'll work on that checker.

Comment: Hey Pax question for you. where should I turn too to learn more about the return values of thing like in this example 1. I know 0 in return means it executed just fine and no errors and returns like 1 and -1 returns errors. Are they the same concept as in the if statement? Hope that makes sense. lol

Comment: Ryan, I use the C standard for this but it's mostly a pretty dry read, so you may want to think about just looking at the manpages, or cplusplus.com. However, as the definitive source for what the functions do, I prefer the standard.